# Two Controls Events on one UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

In iPhone app it's possible to add two UIControlEvents on one unbutton?

I want to add Touch Up Inside and Touch Drag Exit, I tried to add Touch Up Inside in IB then in viewDidLoad I add Touch Drag Exit programmatically by using the following code:

[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(method:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];

It's work but I'm wondering it won't cause my app to crash?!

Thanks.

Comment: Of course it won't make your app crash, what if you want to have different actions on `TouchUpInside` and `TouchUpOutside`? It won't crash.

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely add multiple events to controls. If you have overlapping events, some of your events might not fire but it wont crash your application.

More about event programming: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html